# TextBlock rotation

Tags: xaml, uno-platform

I'm using this xaml code in Uno:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Goodday" >
   <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
     <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
   </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>  
</TextBlock>
```

But text doen not rotate.
Any clue?

Comment: Can you mention which platform you're running this on? and post screenshots? Also, I think you could have meant `RenderTransform`, not `LayoutTransform`?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try wrapping the `TextBlock` in a `Grid` then apply the render transform on the grid (and maybe open a GitHub issue in https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues so this can be looked into why it's not working.)